# Moodle custom profile field: radio

Tags: php, moodle

I'm using Moodle 2.8 and I am trying to make a radio custom profile field for the register form. I got it working almost well, but when I save the form, the value is set always to cero. However, if I set a default value, let´s say 1, it will show correctly at this value and save with this value. But again, even if I change it, it will always be 1. It looks like doesn't take the change when I click or something, but I even have an idsabledif option depending on this radio value and it works when I change it.

Comment: Can you show the code? Is it on github or bitbucket?

Comment: Ok thanks. I put it here:
http://paste.ofcode.org/g7bkTRtXgytqgMQ9LdWQwc
thats the field.class.php
and this is the define.class.php
http://paste.ofcode.org/SdhpasyaqetKRLjVruGRs9